# Using vue3 component in sweetalert2 content

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, sweetalert, sweetalert2, vue-sweetalert2

I'm trying to use a Vue3 component inside the Sweetalert2 modal. It would be something like this:

```js
<template>
  <div id="test-component">
    <h1>Yeey!</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TestComponent",
};
</script>
```

*TestComponent.vue*

and in other component use sweetalert modal like:

```js
<script>
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import TestComponent from "@/components/TestComponent";

export default {
  name: "OtherComponent",
  methods: {
    clickAction() {
      Swal.fire({ html: '<TestComponent />' });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I don't even know if this is possible, but I saw a couple of examples using Vue2 so, here I am trying to figure out how to do that on Vue3.

Doing this way, the sweetalert is displayed empty, and inside the `swal2-html-container` has:

```html
<div class="swal2-html-container" id="swal2-html-container" style="display: block;">
  <testcomponent></testcomponent>
</div>
```

Without rendering the actual component.

Comment: whats current results